# What's wrong with my HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've created an Html extension method in Helper class, but I can not get it to work. I've implemented it as seen on different tutorials.

My MenuItemHelper static class:

```
public static string MenuItem(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        var currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (currentControllerName.Equals(controllerName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && currentActionName.Equals(actionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            sb.Append("<li class=\"selected\">");
        else
            sb.Append("<li>");

        sb.Append(helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName));
        sb.Append("</li>");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

import namespace

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MYAPP.Web.App.Helpers" %>
```

Implementation on my master.page

```
<%= Html.MenuItem("TEST LINK", "About", "Site") %>
```

The error message I get:

> Method not found: 'System.String System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String, System.String, System.String)

**EDIT:**
Seem like the problem is the application name. 
the folder is called MYAPP-MVC.Web, but in the classes it translates to MYAPP_MVC.Web

I just tried it on a fresh application and it works

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? What is the version of the System.Web.Mvc.dll file?

Comment: Are you **sure** MenuItem is defined in the MYAPP.Web.App.Helpers namespace?

Comment: Sorry about that it's MVC 2
@Eric J. yep sure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try rewriting your helper in a more ASP.NET MVCish 2.0 style. Also don't forget to add using `System.Web.Mvc.Html` inside your helper namespace so that you have access to the `ActionLink` method:

```
namespace MYAPP.Web.App.Helpers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper helper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
        {
            var currentControllerName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var currentActionName = (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

            var li = new TagBuilder("li");
            if (string.Equals(currentControllerName, controllerName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
                string.Equals(currentActionName, actionName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                li.AddCssClass("selected");
            }

            li.InnerHtml = helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString();
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If this doesn't work you are definitely having some version problems with the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly being used.

Comment: +1 - good points about using the `TagBuilder` and returning `MvcHtmlString`. The OP should be using the new encoding syntax to `<%: ... %>`

Comment: Good thing about the Tagbuilder, I will use that instead. Thanks Darin
@ Russ, I'm on 3.5 not 4.0

Comment: @ Darin is the MvcHtmlString 4.0 only?

Comment: No, it's not .NET 4.0 only, it's ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Comment: @Darin Yeah but <%: ... %> is .NET 4 only

Comment: @Yes, but the question was is `MvcHtmlString` .NET 4.0 only and the answer is no. And why not be ready for it when it comes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the extension method available to the page/viewpage. You can do this for the individual page by adding a directive to the top of it

```
<%@ Import namespace="Namespace.Where.Your.HtmlHelper.Extension.Is.Defined" %>
```

or you can make it available to all pages by adding it to the

```
<pages> 
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Namespace.Where.Your.HtmlHelper.Extension.Is.Defined" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

section in web.config.

**EDIT:**

The problem might be to do with the fact that `HtmlHelper.ActionLink()` returns an `MvcHtmlString` and not a `string`. I think you should call `ToString()` on it when calling append with the `StringBuilder`. As has been pointed out, ideally you ought to be returning `MvcHtmlString` so that others can use your extension method with the `<%: ... %>` syntax and not have the output encoded again.

Comment: You mean the namespace? if so that is already done, i do the imports.

Comment: And you get intellisense that indicates your extension method is found and can be used?

Comment: Yep but I think I found the problem, check my edit.. thanks for reply Russ

Comment: yes, you're right :) For any data that is potentially coming from the user though, you should be encoding it to mitigate injection attacks. It doesn't look as though that's necessary in this particular case, but it is a good practice to get into.